# postgresql query returned successfully with no result while creating view

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, postgresql-9.2

I have created a view from table as

```
CREATE VIEW dp_val_view
AS
select dp_id,dp_id,dp_s,dp_n,dp_ord,id,answer,date,eny_date
from
 (
    select select dp_id,dp_id,dp_s,dp_n,dp_ord,id,answer,date,eny_date,row_number(*)
    over (partition by dp_id ,dp_ord ,id order by eny_date desc ) as rn
    from values 
 ) dt
where rn < 2
```

view created successfull and i got as query returned successfully with no result...After that when i am trying to access table data it is daying refreshing table please .Does it mean value from table is getting inserted into view in background ?

Comment: What result did you expect? "Returned successfully with no result" seems right. Also, view is not physically storing the table data anywhere, so no background inserts. Where do you see the text "refreshing table please"?

Answer (score 0):

A view is only a "shortcut" for a query. No data is stored in a (regular) view and no data is "inserted" when you run `create view`.

And because `create view` only stores the *query* in the database, it does not "return" any results just like a `create table` does not return any results from that table.

When you select form the view, the database runs the underlying query. It's exactly the same as if you had run the query directly.

Answer (score 0):

Views are just wrappers, or in other terms we can say alias for the longer query.

Nothing gets inserted into the view, when you query the view, internally it will execute the select query which you have specified.

A good explanation is in the manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html

> The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run every time the view is referenced in a query.